# STS vFabric Server Developer Edition not accessible from remote

Tags: spring-mvc

Hi I successfully run my webapp in STS builtin tc Server. 
I can access it from localhost but not from remote computers.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not a problem with spring / tc Server.

try to ping the server from your remote computer

get the IP of your server with `ipconfig` then try to ping it

```
ping http://10.xx.xxx.12/yourapp
```

Then check if you have any firewall that blocks the incoming network traffic.
or other program such as Norton / Symantec antivirus that include a "Network Security Threat" feature to block the traffic.

If you have such program, create a rule to grant access to the clients you want to access your server